# How to apply an Excel event handler to all sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I've created VBA that manipulates the cells in my current sheet (triggered by a SelectionChange event handler).

How can I make this trigger in *any* of the sheets in my workbook? (The action should only react to, and modify, the sheet that's currently active.)

Here's an example: It takes the value of the current cell, and copies it to "A1":

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Cells(1, 1).Value = Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value
End Sub
```

(The real code is rather more complex —and constant WiP—, so I don't really want to copy it to each and every sheet.)

Comment: Have you tried [Workbook_SheetSelectionChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetselectionchange) .. So it will be like `Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Cells(1, TargetColumn + 1).Value = Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value
End Sub`

Comment: copies it to "A1" ?? No.. Then why .`Cells(1, TargetColumn + 1).Value` instead of `Cells(1,1)` ?. Also, you can refer just as `Target` instead of  `Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value`

Comment: It's VBA not VBScript.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Workbook_SheetSelectionChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetselectionchange) instead of Worksheet_SelectionChange seems to work.

It should be noted though, that the script then has to be placed into the *ThisWorkbook* code window (instead of the one for Sheet1).

Answer (score 0):

I have a xlam file, on that I defined new class

**Class Module**

```
Public WithEvents appEvent As Application
    
Private Sub appEvent_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
  ' Here is your code to be executed            
End Sub
```

First insert a new module, then declare next public variable based on the class defined above

```
Public myApp As New cEventSelectionChange
```

After that create a new Sub procedure.

```
Sub defineEventSelectionChange()
  Set myApp.appEvent = Application
End Sub
```

This sub will be called from the other event in ThisWorkbook.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()    
   Call defineEventSelectionChange
End Sub
```

The code above will be executed every time you open the Excel application.
Remember the Add-On xlam needs to be enabled.